# How to do retry logic Spring Boot Reactive framework

Tags: spring-boot, reactive

In my Sprint boot application, I am calling an external API to validate some data, whenever API is down or there is some network delay,
I get an SSLHandShakeException/Exception and then it reconnects.
I want to add a retry logic that can try for 5 times whenever there is an exception.
I tried the following way, I wanted to know if there is a better way of doing this.

```
public Mono<ResponseObj> getInfo(String xxxxx) {
            return serviceCall.findBy(xxxx)
                    .map()
                    .map()
                    .switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(() -> fetchResponse(xxxxx)));
        }
        
        private Mono<ResponseObj> fetchResponse(String xxxxx) 
            return getInfo(xxxxx)
                    .onErrorResume(e -> throwError(xxxxx))

                    .retryWhen(Retry.fixedDelay(5, Duration.ofSeconds(20))
                            .filter(this::is5xxServerError))
                    .map(res -> proceedOrThrowError(xxxx))
                    .flatMap()
                    .map()
                    .map();

        }
        
         private Mono<ResponseObj> getInfo(String xxxx) 
            return ThrowingFunction
                    .unchecked(x ->
                            webClient.get()
                                    .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder
                                            .path(url + "/" + xxxx)
                                            .build())
                                    .bodyToMono(ResponseObj.class))
                    .apply(xxxx);
        }
        
         private boolean is5xxServerError(Throwable throwable) {
            return throwable instanceof WebClientResponseException &&
                    ((WebClientResponseException) throwable).getStatusCode().is5xxServerError();
        }
```